# How do I tune WordPress to make my site more responsive?

Tags: ram, wordpress, optimization

I have a Linode that has Ubuntu loaded and am hosting a WordPress site.  I would like to optimize my site so that I no longer get Out of Memory errors like the following:

> Killed process 16660 (apache2) total-vm:186232kB, anon-rss:87404kB, file-rss:0kB

I have 512 MB of RAM and whenever I get a spike of 500+ users trying to access the site, the site becomes unresponsive and I start getting the errors above.

What optimizations can I make to help improve site performance?

Answer (score 2):

If you have full root access to the box, you might want to look at some of the tweaks on [Elliott C. Back's Post: Why My Site Is So Much Faster Than Yours](http://elliottback.com/wp/why-my-wordpress-site-is-so-much-faster-than-yours/). Some can be done on Non Root enabled boxes (like W3 Super Cache, which i use for my own sites), but others may need root access for (like tweaking MySQL, PHP OpCode, Apache and Kernel tweaks).

Comment: This is something more along the lines of what I was looking for.  Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 0):

The best is to remove unnecessary plug-in(s) that your site doesn't need. I had the problem, by one plug-in that keep me from writing any new post, removing that plug-in made everything correct and solved my problem.

if you can - request a log file from your hosting provider, so you can have a look at what things in your wordpress (actually FTP) makes your site slower.

You can also look at your theme - is it generated to work effectively in Wordpress, and in what version of Wordpress - different versions and themes that isn't compatible can also sometimes slow the site down.

make sure on the front end - viewing the site, you don't have any thing like flash or pop-up menus - that has to load and have to open up when the viewer do something on the site. This can also slow things down.

Hope this is a little guide line to help you.

Comment: I am actually looking at tweaking my apache2.conf so that it can handle a load of ~500 requests.

Comment: I think that is something that you should discus with your hosting company - they will be able to assist you better.